# How to find dynamically loaded element using selenium webdriver FinnONe Automation

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

**How can I use Selenium locators to find and click the Termination menu item below?** It does not become visible until I've clicked through the parent menu items.

Page code:

```
<html>
<head>
<body>

<script src="/javalms/common/jscript/menu/menu_com.js" type="text/javascript">
<link href="/javalms/common/css/megamenu.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/javalms/common/css/bootstrap-common.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script>
  Menu1= new Array('Authorizers Desk','','',3,ItemHeight,ItemWidth);      
  Menu1_1= new Array('Loan Processing','','',8,ItemHeight,ItemWidth); 
  Menu6= new Array('Processes','','',2,ItemHeight,ItemWidth); 
  Menu1_2= new Array('Settlements','','',7,ItemHeight,ItemWidth); 
  Menu5= new Array('References','','',1,ItemHeight,ItemWidth); 
  Menu4_4= new Array('DownLoads','','',1,ItemHeight,ItemWidth); 
  Menu1_1_3= new Array('Documents','','',2,ItemHeight,ItemWidth);  
  Menu3_11= new Array('NPA and Provisioning','','',4,ItemHeight,ItemWidth); 
  Menu4= new Array('Ops&Control','','',13,ItemHeight,ItemWidth); 
  Menu4_1= new Array('Reports','','',13,ItemHeight,ItemWidth); 
  Menu4_13= new Array('Unapplied Credit Reports','','',2,ItemHeight,ItemWidth); 
  Menu1_1_7= new Array('NPA and Provisioning','','',1,ItemHeight,ItemWidth); 
  Menu7=new Array('Help','javascript:openWindow()','',0,ItemHeight,37);
</script>
<script src="/javalms/common/jscript/Validation.js" type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
<script src="/javalms/common/jscript/SHA256.js" type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
<script src="/javalms/common/jscript/MDLogin.js" type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
<script src="/javalms/common/jscript/AlertFileen.js" type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
<link href="/javalms/common/css/LendingLTR.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script>
<script>
<script>
<input id="hidTimerCtr" type="hidden" name="hidTimerCtr" value="200">
<input id="hidTimerVal" type="hidden" name="hidTimerVal" value="1500">
<script>
<script src="/javalms/common/jscript/LovValidation.js" type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
<script src="/javalms/common/jscript/ChangeBranch.js" type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
<script language="javascript">
<style type="text/css">
<form action="/javalms/loginCheck.do" name="LoginAF" method="post">
<form action="/javalms/loginCheck.do" name="LoginAF" method="post">
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<table width="100%">
<div bgcolor="#3993BA" orgleft="1" orgtop="80" style="Z-INDEX: 101; POSITION: absolute; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #3993ba; FONT-STYLE: normal; WIDTH: 1083px; FONT-FAMILY: sans-serif; HEIGHT: 28px; VISIBILITY: visible; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; TOP: 80px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; LEFT: 1px">
<div orgleft="0" orgtop="28" style="Z-INDEX: 102; POSITION: absolute; FONT-STYLE: normal; WIDTH: 175px; FONT-FAMILY: sans-serif; HEIGHT: 82px; VISIBILITY: visible; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; TOP: 108px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; LEFT: 1px">
<div orgleft="172.27" orgtop="0" style="Z-INDEX: 103; POSITION: absolute; FONT-STYLE: normal; WIDTH: 175px; FONT-FAMILY: sans-serif; HEIGHT: 217px; VISIBILITY: visible; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; TOP: 108px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; LEFT: 173px">
<div hifntclr="#ffffff" hibck="#336699" lwfntclr="#000000" lobck="#E6E6E6" value="Post Disbursal Edits" ro="0" hilite="0" childcntnr="null" linktxt="lms/loanprocessing/agreement/AgreementAC.do?mode=searchAgreement&makerchakerflag=C&activity=PDE&taskid=124" level="3" prvmbr="null" style="POSITION: absolute; TEXT-ALIGN: left; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #e6e6e6; PADDING-LEFT: 2px; WIDTH: 173px; HEIGHT: 26px; VISIBILITY: inherit; COLOR: #000000; OVERFLOW: hidden; TOP: 1px; CURSOR: hand; PADDING-TOP: 6px; LEFT: 1px">Post Disbursal Edits</div>
<div hifntclr="#ffffff" hibck="#336699" lwfntclr="#000000" lobck="#E6E6E6" value="Property Details" ro="0" hilite="0" childcntnr="null" linktxt="lms/loanprocessing/property/action/PropertyAC.do?makerchakerflag=C&taskid=127" level="3" style="POSITION: absolute; TEXT-ALIGN: left; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #e6e6e6; PADDING-LEFT: 2px; WIDTH: 173px; HEIGHT: 26px; VISIBILITY: inherit; COLOR: #000000; OVERFLOW: hidden; TOP: 28px; CURSOR: hand; PADDING-TOP: 6px; LEFT: 1px">Property Details</div>
<div hifntclr="#ffffff" hibck="#336699" lwfntclr="#000000" lobck="#E6E6E6" value="Documents" ro="0" hilite="0" linktxt="" level="3" style="POSITION: absolute; TEXT-ALIGN: left; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #e6e6e6; PADDING-LEFT: 2px; WIDTH: 173px; HEIGHT: 26px; VISIBILITY: inherit; COLOR: #000000; OVERFLOW: hidden; TOP: 55px; CURSOR: default; PADDING-TOP: 6px; LEFT: 1px">Documents</div>
<div hifntclr="#ffffff" hibck="#336699" lwfntclr="#000000" lobck="#E6E6E6" value="Cancellation" ro="0" hilite="0" childcntnr="null" linktxt="lms/loanprocessing/loancancellation/loanCancellationQueryAC.do?mode=OPEN&amp;mc=C&amp;op=LOANCANCEL&taskid=125" level="3" style="POSITION: absolute; TEXT-ALIGN: left; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #e6e6e6; PADDING-LEFT: 2px; WIDTH: 173px; HEIGHT: 26px; VISIBILITY: inherit; COLOR: #000000; OVERFLOW: hidden; TOP: 82px; CURSOR: hand; PADDING-TOP: 6px; LEFT: 1px">Cancellation</div>
<div hifntclr="#ffffff" hibck="#336699" lwfntclr="#000000" lobck="#E6E6E6" value="Rescheduling / Bulk Refund" ro="0" hilite="0" childcntnr="null" linktxt="lms/loanprocessing/agreement/AgreementAC.do?mode=searchAgreement&makerchakerflag=A&activity=RCHD&taskid=121" level="3" style="POSITION: absolute; TEXT-ALIGN: left; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #e6e6e6; PADDING-LEFT: 2px; WIDTH: 173px; HEIGHT: 26px; VISIBILITY: inherit; COLOR: #000000; OVERFLOW: hidden; TOP: 109px; CURSOR: hand; PADDING-TOP: 6px; LEFT: 1px">Rescheduling / Bulk Refund</div>
<div hifntclr="#ffffff" hibck="#336699" lwfntclr="#000000" lobck="#E6E6E6" value="Termination" ro="0" hilite="0" childcntnr="null" linktxt="util/listViewQueryAC.do?mode=OPEN&amp;mc=C&amp;op=T&amp;ot=FD&taskid=122" level="3" style="POSITION: absolute; TEXT-ALIGN: left; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #e6e6e6; PADDING-LEFT: 2px; WIDTH: 173px; HEIGHT: 26px; VISIBILITY: inherit; COLOR: #000000; OVERFLOW: hidden; TOP: 136px; CURSOR: hand; PADDING-TOP: 6px; LEFT: 1px">Termination</div>
<div hifntclr="#ffffff" hibck="#336699" lwfntclr="#000000" lobck="#E6E6E6" value="NPA and Provisioning" ro="0" hilite="0" linktxt="" level="3" style="POSITION: absolute; TEXT-ALIGN: left; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #e6e6e6; PADDING-LEFT: 2px; WIDTH: 173px; HEIGHT: 26px; VISIBILITY: inherit; COLOR: #000000; OVERFLOW: hidden; TOP: 163px; CURSOR: default; PADDING-TOP: 6px; LEFT: 1px">NPA and Provisioning</div>
<div hifntclr="#ffffff" hibck="#336699" lwfntclr="#000000" lobck="#E6E6E6" value="Asset Details-Info Updation" ro="0" hilite="0" childcntnr="null" linktxt="lms/loanprocessing/assetdetails/assetinformation/jsp/AssetInformationQuery.do?method=menu&mode=A&taskid=137" level="3" style="POSITION: absolute; TEXT-ALIGN: left; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #e6e6e6; PADDING-LEFT: 2px; WIDTH: 173px; HEIGHT: 26px; VISIBILITY: inherit; COLOR: #000000; OVERFLOW: hidden; TOP: 190px; CURSOR: hand; PADDING-TOP: 6px; LEFT: 1px">Asset Details-Info Updation</div>
</div>
<div orgleft="172.27" orgtop="54" style="Z-INDEX: 104; POSITION: absolute; FONT-STYLE: normal; WIDTH: 175px; FONT-FAMILY: sans-serif; HEIGHT: 55px; VISIBILITY: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; TOP: 0px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; LEFT: 0px">
<div orgleft="172.27" orgtop="162" style="Z-INDEX: 104; POSITION: absolute; FONT-STYLE: normal; WIDTH: 175px; FONT-FAMILY: sans-serif; HEIGHT: 28px; VISIBILITY: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; TOP: 0px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; LEFT: 0px">
<div orgleft="172.27" orgtop="27" style="Z-INDEX: 103; POSITION: absolute; FONT-STYLE: normal; WIDTH: 175px; FONT-FAMILY: sans-serif; HEIGHT: 190px; VISIBILITY: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; TOP: 0px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; LEFT: 0px">
<div orgleft="174" orgtop="28" style="Z-INDEX: 102; POSITION: absolute; FONT-STYLE: normal; WIDTH: 175px; FONT-FAMILY: sans-serif; HEIGHT: 109px; VISIBILITY: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; TOP: 0px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; LEFT: 0px">
<div orgleft="172.27" orgtop="0" style="Z-INDEX: 103; POSITION: absolute; FONT-STYLE: normal; WIDTH: 175px; FONT-FAMILY: sans-serif; HEIGHT: 55px; VISIBILITY: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; TOP: 0px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; LEFT: 0px">
<div orgleft="348" orgtop="28" style="Z-INDEX: 102; POSITION: absolute; FONT-STYLE: normal; WIDTH: 175px; FONT-FAMILY: sans-serif; HEIGHT: 298px; VISIBILITY: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; TOP: 0px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; LEFT: 0px">
<div orgleft="172.27" orgtop="0" style="Z-INDEX: 103; POSITION: absolute; FONT-STYLE: normal; WIDTH: 175px; FONT-FAMILY: sans-serif; HEIGHT: 28px; VISIBILITY: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; TOP: 0px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; LEFT: 0px">
<div orgleft="172.27" orgtop="54" style="Z-INDEX: 103; POSITION: absolute; FONT-STYLE: normal; WIDTH: 175px; FONT-FAMILY: sans-serif; HEIGHT: 55px; VISIBILITY: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; TOP: 0px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; LEFT: 0px">
<div orgleft="172.27" orgtop="108" style="Z-INDEX: 103; POSITION: absolute; FONT-STYLE: normal; WIDTH: 175px; FONT-FAMILY: sans-serif; HEIGHT: 190px; VISIBILITY: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; TOP: 0px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; LEFT: 0px">
<div orgleft="172.27" orgtop="162" style="Z-INDEX: 103; POSITION: absolute; FONT-STYLE: normal; WIDTH: 175px; FONT-FAMILY: sans-serif; HEIGHT: 82px; VISIBILITY: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; TOP: 0px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; LEFT: 0px">
<div orgleft="172.27" orgtop="270" style="Z-INDEX: 103; POSITION: absolute; FONT-STYLE: normal; WIDTH: 175px; FONT-FAMILY: sans-serif; HEIGHT: 109px; VISIBILITY: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; TOP: 0px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; LEFT: 0px">
<div orgleft="522" orgtop="28" style="Z-INDEX: 102; POSITION: absolute; FONT-STYLE: normal; WIDTH: 175px; FONT-FAMILY: sans-serif; HEIGHT: 366px; VISIBILITY: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; TOP: 0px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; LEFT: 0px">
<div orgleft="172.27" orgtop="0" style="Z-INDEX: 103; POSITION: absolute; FONT-STYLE: normal; WIDTH: 175px; FONT-FAMILY: sans-serif; HEIGHT: 352px; VISIBILITY: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; TOP: 0px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; LEFT: 0px">
<div orgleft="172.27" orgtop="0" style="Z-INDEX: 104; POSITION: absolute; FONT-STYLE: normal; WIDTH: 175px; FONT-FAMILY: sans-serif; HEIGHT: 28px; VISIBILITY: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; TOP: 0px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; LEFT: 0px">
<div orgleft="172.27" orgtop="27" style="Z-INDEX: 104; POSITION: absolute; FONT-STYLE: normal; WIDTH: 175px; FONT-FAMILY: sans-serif; HEIGHT: 109px; VISIBILITY: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; TOP: 0px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; LEFT: 0px">
<div orgleft="172.27" orgtop="54" style="Z-INDEX: 104; POSITION: absolute; FONT-STYLE: normal; WIDTH: 175px; FONT-FAMILY: sans-serif; HEIGHT: 28px; VISIBILITY: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; TOP: 0px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; LEFT: 0px">
<div orgleft="172.27" orgtop="81" style="Z-INDEX: 104; POSITION: absolute; FONT-STYLE: normal; WIDTH: 175px; FONT-FAMILY: sans-serif; HEIGHT: 82px; VISIBILITY: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; TOP: 0px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; LEFT: 0px">
<div orgleft="172.27" orgtop="81" style="Z-INDEX: 103; POSITION: absolute; FONT-STYLE: normal; WIDTH: 175px; FONT-FAMILY: sans-serif; HEIGHT: 28px; VISIBILITY: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; TOP: 0px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; LEFT: 0px">
<div orgleft="172.27" orgtop="338" style="Z-INDEX: 103; POSITION: absolute; FONT-STYLE: normal; WIDTH: 175px; FONT-FAMILY: sans-serif; HEIGHT: 55px; VISIBILITY: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; TOP: 0px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; LEFT: 0px">
<div orgleft="696" orgtop="28" style="Z-INDEX: 102; POSITION: absolute; FONT-STYLE: normal; WIDTH: 175px; FONT-FAMILY: sans-serif; HEIGHT: 28px; VISIBILITY: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; TOP: 0px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; LEFT: 0px">
<div orgleft="870" orgtop="28" style="Z-INDEX: 102; POSITION: absolute; FONT-STYLE: normal; WIDTH: 175px; FONT-FAMILY: sans-serif; HEIGHT: 55px; VISIBILITY: hidden; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; TOP: 0px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; LEFT: 0px">
</body>
</html>
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scenario to deal with this kind of element is

1. Click on Menu element, submenu get visible now
2. Click on submenu now

So tho handle this you have to use `Actions` class. Use below example to handle the same :

```
WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.your_locatorForMenuElement);
WebElement submenu = driver.findElement(By.your_locatorForMenuElement);

Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(menu).clickAndHold(submenu).click().build().perform();
```

Let me know if you have any trouble.

Comment: OP didn't specify language, but +1 for the good java example, although I'm not clear on why you need to click an hold?

Comment: Thnx narendra, it worked for me, but sometimes it losses menu focus because of this some other element gets click.

Comment: @YashShrivastava, If this answer is helpful for you then do not forget to `Accept` by click on right tick below vote count. it may helpful for others. Thanks :)

Comment: @NarendraRajput yes its working now thnx, i also would like to ask u how to find value from nested <div> or nested <frameset> example code are:: <div bgcolor="#3993BA" orgleft="1" orgtop="80" style="Z-INDEX: 101; POSITION: absolute; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #3993ba; FONT-STYLE: normal; WIDTH: 1083px; FONT-FAMILY: sans-serif; HEIGHT: 28px; VISIBILITY: visible; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; TOP: 80px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; LEFT: 1px">
<div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div>

Comment: @YashShrivastava, here I'm not seeing any element in your posted code. even you can get the nested things by text too. e.g. here you want to get `Termination` witch is under `div` tag  so just make xpath like `//div[contains(text(),'Termination')]`

Comment: @NarendraRajput hey thax its done, but different question arise at work, could you please tell me How to read outlook unread mail and fetching the data. the mail is receiving from particulate mail id. first i have to check that mail id is correct then check it unread then fetch the details data and the create excel(write in excel) as per the data columns.